# I can’t find my ”rigidbody” tab on the right Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Yo ! I was programming on Unity and I wanted to modify something about the collision detection but when I click on any object but my player 1 on the scene I can’t find that tab. Did I mess up somewhere ? I put a video for more info.

Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnmnpgYWKUA&t=1s

```
// The script that makes the camera follow my player :

using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPerso1 : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform perso1;
public Vector3 offset;

// Use this for initialization
// void Start ()

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    transform.position = perso1.position +  offset;
}
}

// The script that makes the collision possibles :1

using UnityEngine;

public class Perso1Collision : MonoBehaviour {

public Perso1Movement Movement;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == “Obstacle”)
    {
        Movement.enabled = false;
    }
}

}

 // The script that makes the movements possible :

 using UnityEngine;

 public class Perso1Movement : MonoBehaviour {

public Rigidbody rb;

public float forwardForce = 2000f; // <– We declared a variable float to            change out forwardForce (REVOIR)… E03
public float sidewaysForce = 500f; // REVOIR

// Use this for initialization
// void Start ()

// voidUpdate : Update is called once per frame (So the force ”speed” will depend on how many FPS your PC has)
void FixedUpdate () // FixedUpdate is better to calculate Physics in Unity (”makes stuff looks smoother when you collide with stuff”. Ref. Brackeys EP.2 HTMVGIU)
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime); // <– NOTE : Gotta understand Time.deltaTime better

    if (Input.GetKey(“d”)) // <– QUESTION : Why not ”D” and ”d” instead ? :O
    {
        rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(“a”)) // <– QUESTION : Why not ”D” and ”d” instead ? :O
    {
        rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange); // Understand ForceMode.VelocityChange better E06
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add it? On the bottom of the inspector click on `Add Component` and either input `RigidBody` in the textfield on the top or search it under the physics category (should be the 1st entry)

Rigidbody is no default component, you have to intentionally add it to your GameObjects (infact only Transform is default, but the primitives like cubes ofc need a meshfilter and renderer to display, and conveniently also come with boxcollider "out of the box")

I hope it was that and I could help.

Edit:
If you just start out with unity I would suggest to you going over the official tutorials on the unity-website so you get a general idea of how everything works. They are quite well made.

Here is the Rigidbody tutorial for example: https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/rigidbodies?playlist=17120

Comment: I second this, start with the official tutorials.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks so much I just started out with and you are right I should do the officials tutorials ! I thought I messed up something so I couldn't find it but like you said it isn't by default so I had to add at least on most of my objects it wasn't default I'm not sure ! Thank you very much ! :D Also I don't get why ppl downvote beginners' posts so easily it's just stupid and mean.

Comment: i guess its because often people dont show the slightest effort in research and try to abuse stackoverflow as their personal teachers and code monkeys. and to be honest hadnt you put so much effort in this question and even recorded a youtube video, i had not answered either because its really basic. but then, i also know sometimes you just get stuck and dont see the solution even though its right before your eye. also im completely self-taught myself, i know what a PITA it can be, especially in the beginning. is it nice to downvote? no. understandable? maybe. anyway, happy coding.:)

Comment: @Tech also please, when it helps you, tick the answer as correct. there are way too many still open threads on this site, especially in the unity subcategory.

Comment: Alright thanks ! Btw recording a video is better than a 1000 words and how was I supposed to know ? Like wtf... I'm a F******* beginner.

Comment: Also I can't find how to ''tick'' an anwser I don't think I've got enough reputation for that. I guess...

Comment: @Tech now you caught me red handed, i dont have the slightest clue how to mark an answer as correct, i have no asked anything yet - though i suspect it has something to do with the number-thingy next to my reply. i also did not mean to offend you, i just tried to understand why people did downvote you. i fully get you, its really hard to know what you have to search for if you dont know whats wrong. so seriously, no offense meant. and for the rest, well, just ignore the haters :D